# Local and global references with UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, function, global, local

I don't quite understand why the code

```
def f():
    print(s)

s = "foo"
f()
```

runs perfectly fine but

```
def f():
    print(s)
    s = "bar"

s = "foo"
f()
```

gives me UnboundLocalError. I know that I can fix this by declaring *s* as a global variable inside the function or by simply passing *s* an an argument into the function.

Still I don't understand how python seemingly knows whether or not s is referenced inside the function before the line has been executed? Does python make some sort of list of all local variable references when the function is read into the global frame?

Comment: function objects do appear to know all that stuff. You can inspect using `f.__code__`. That has properties like `co_nlocals`, `co_varnames` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have focused on the practical aspects of this but have not actually answered the question you asked.

Yes, the Python compiler tracks which variables are assigned when it is compiling a code block (such as in a `def`).  If a name is assigned to in a block, the compiler marks it as local.Take a look at `function.__code__.co_varnames` to see which variables the compiler has identified.

The `nonlocal` and `global` statements can override this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python will look-ahead to recover all variables declared in the local scope. These will then overshadow global variables.

So in your code:

```
def f():
    print(s)

s = "foo"
f()
```

Python did not find `s` in the local scope, so it tries to recover it from the global scope and finds `"foo"`.

Now in the other case the following happens:

```
def f():
    print(s)
    s = "bar

s = "foo"
f()
```

Python knows that `s` is a local variable because it did a look-ahead before runtime, but at runtime it was not assigned yet so it raised and exception.

Note that Python will even let you reference variables that have not been declared anywhere. If you do:

```
def foo():
    return x
f()
```

You will get a `NameError`, because Python, when not finding, `x` as a local variable will just remember that at runtime it should look for a global variable named `x` and then fail if it does not exist.

So `UnboundLocalError` means that the variable may eventually be declared in scope but has not been yet. On the other hand `NameError` means that the variable will never be declared in the local scope, so Python tried to find it in the global scope, but it did not exist.

Comment: You are not referencing bar before it was declared. You are just defining a function! `bar` will get referenced in run time and being a global will exist before local scope of function `foo`!

Comment: Yes, you are referencing to the global name bar. And since Python uses hash tables to recover its variables, it just remembers that at runtime it should hash bar, and recover the corresponding value from the global scope.

Comment: @ElisByberi I see what you mean I think, I'll clarify that Python does not actually declares variables.

Comment: **I am not going to repeat it anymore!** Global variable `bar` (it is a function is this case) does exist before local scope of function `foo`. You are not referencing anything when you just define functions. It will be referenced in run time and it will exist before being referenced in function `foo`.

Comment: Are you talking about the def bar(x) or the return bar(x)?

Comment: `Python assumes it is a global variable` Python does not assume. If in local scope **does exist any variable that override any global variable**, this global can not be accessed inside function anymore.

Comment: I am talking about variable in `return bar(x)`, returning defined function/variable in `def bar(x)`.

Comment: I'll remove the ... since it seems to be confusing and make you assume I declare a local bar in the function foo

Comment: You are going off-topic a little bit. See question again.

Comment: Yes you are right... The answer should just be 'yes Python looks-ahead to recover declared variables in the scope to overshadow the global variables'