# Why do these two examples appear to handle local/global variable assignments differently?

Tags: python

Example 1:

```
x = 5
def dE():
    x = 6 + x
    print(x)
dE()
print(x)
```

which outputs:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Example 2:

```
x = [1,8,2,1,6,3,7,6,4,12,13]
def dE():
    i = len(x) - 1
    while (i >= 0):
        currVal = x[i]
        if (currVal % 2 == 0):
            del(x[i])
        i = i - 1
    print(x)
dE()
print(x)
```

which outputs:

```
[1, 1, 3, 7, 13]
[1, 1, 3, 7, 13]
```

When defining a function in Python, my understanding is that variable assignments that happen within the function (local) do not affect (or create) variables outside of the function (global), and vice versa, unless they're explicitly called as `global` within the function.

This can be seen in Example 1, in which the function tries to assign `6 + x` to `x` and can't because `x` wasn't previously defined within the function and was never declared as `global`.

However, in Example 2, a list is assigned to `x` outside of/before the function. Then, within the function, `x` is neither declared `global` nor defined, just like Example 1, but IS able to be used and manipulated within the function. Further, printing `x` both at the end of the function definition and outside of the function definition after the function is called give the same result.

What is the difference between these two examples?

Comment: Seems to be a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620697/local-and-global-references-with-unboundlocalerror).

Comment: In example two you are never _assigning_ to `x`, so there is no rebinding, `x` is just modified in-place which is ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local and global references with UnboundLocalError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620697/local-and-global-references-with-unboundlocalerror)

Answer (score 0):

Assignment is the key. In the second case, an existing variable is mutated, but not *assigned*.

You may read and modify existing global variables, but you cannot assign a new object to a variable without a global statement.